# Create event in mysql that update a record when a datatime column expires

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I create an event in mysql to update a record immediately datetime field expires. I want to auto update a record when a field expires to change the status.
Thanks.

Comment: Why? This seems like an unnecessary activity

Comment: The how - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html do you have a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a view so the value is always accurate?

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*,
           (case when now() >= expire_dt then 'Expired' else 'Active' end) as status
    from t;
```